# I got an error when I implement addTextChangedListener, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, android, keylistener

I create an `EditText` and I set it **addtextchangedlistener**.
code is :

```
 shared_tags.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        shared_tags.setText( shared_tags.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "#"));
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

But it gives error which is below :

```
03-13 23:22:03.384: E/InputEventReceiver(19895): Exception dispatching input event.
03-13 23:22:03.384: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1754)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1720)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:172)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:212)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:325)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6314)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6208)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6755)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3923)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.424: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19895):  at android.wid
03-13 23:22:03.424: D/AndroidRuntime(19895): Shutting down VM
03-13 23:22:03.424: W/dalvikvm(19895): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4132fac8)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1754)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1720)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:172)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:212)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:325)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6314)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6208)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6755)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3923)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3781)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3756)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at com.wub.twostrangers.share_image$3.onTextChanged(share_image.java:236)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7584)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
03-13 23:22:03.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19895):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3
```

my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/shared_tags"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_shared_tags"
            android:singleLine="true"  
            android:maxLength="70" 
            />



</RelativeLayout>
```

When I delete addtextchangedlistener it works and if i put it back when I want to write someting to my edittext it gives this error

### **(after answers)**

I edit my question, I understand the issue, I want to keylistener for my editbox to detect user press space but I want to replace when a user press space immediately, but when I set text on my editbox it will be recursive , how can I fix it?**

How can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: Please post the xml(layout) files being used here.

Comment: `TextView.java:7600` wow, god object in the works.

Comment: I edited my question please look

Comment: i think problem is not with the  addtextchangedlistener . It is somwhere else in your code , because stackoverflow error generally occus due to recurssion. Can you post some more code.

Comment: Dont you need a semicolon at the end

Comment: @user3033613 I use semicolon but the problem is different :(

Comment: @UditKapahi thanks for answering, in that class there is 1200 lines code. When I delete addtextchangedlistener it works and if i put it back when I want to write someting to my edittext it gives this error.

Comment: what type of edittext you are using , is it customized?

Comment: Editable varya hata ondan geliyo galiba

Comment: More code and/or longer stack trace would be helpful

Comment: @user3033613 editable da ise hata çözümü nasıl olacak?

Comment: addTextChangedListener(this)

Comment: http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/03/text-watcher-example-in-android.html?m=1

Comment: Sorry, the problem is this : I want to keylistener for editbox and when a person press space I want to detect it and replace that character with another, so it will be issue because call textchanged and call and call..recursive code

Comment: I edit my question, I understand the issue, I want to keylistener for my editbox to detect user press space but I want to replace when a user press space immediately, but when I set text on my editbox it will be recursive , how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved mine by doing it this way - modify your onTextChangedMethod as follows (and the reason is below):

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    String str = shared_tags.getText().toString();
    if(!str.equals(""))
        shared_tags.setText("");
    // If you want to do something else - do it here
    // Not sure if this will work to identify space - never tried it
    if(!str.contains(" ")) // if this doesn't work try KeyEvent's getAction() method 
        shared_tags.setText("Whatever you want");
}
```

The reason behind this is a little odd (may be a bug) - when no text has been entered, onTextChangedMethod() keeps calling itself and although it does nothing, the continuous calls to itself causes the stack to overflow and throw this error. The infinite recursion is cause due to the onTextChanged() method. If you debug, you will see this.

EDIT: In your updated logs, you can see what I just said. Your sendOnTextChanged() method is getting called repeatedly.

Comment: thans for answer I will try it and turn back soon

Comment: Sorry, the problem is this : I want to keylistener for editbox and when a person press space I want to detect it and replace that character with another, so it will be issue because call textchanged and call and call..

Comment: Yes, in your case, you need to include your code below the if clause and it should work fine. I edited my answer.

Comment: **!str.equals(" ")** equal? or contains? and I want to replace if I press space so **not equal** or **equal**

Comment: Thank you , if you update your answer like this I tick for you , the answer is **if(str.contains(" ")){
//....
}**